# Accept all cookies banner on StackExchange site button not working and not disappear when I click in Parrot OS Vmware VM Browser

Tags: firefox, vmware, privacy, parrot-os

Accept all cookies banner on StackExhange site button not working and not disappear when I click ACCEPT ALL OR SETTINGS in Parrot OS Vmware Parrot os Virtual Machine

[image]

Comment: It is a Parrot issue and not likely a VMware issue (I use VMware and guest machines).

Comment: Disable all your addons, blockers and other extensions and try again.

Comment: Your browser in not on the list of supported browsers [Stack Overflow browser support](https://browsers.stackoverflow.design/)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.